# How do I test Mocha/Chai to verify that a variable was assigned a value?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai

Let's say I have a function that assigns a value to a variable. How do I go about testing that in Mocha/Chai?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're testing an object or you have a getter of some sort you really can't test properly as testing external state like that is not possible.

Take this for example:

`x.js`

```
const x = 0

const addX = (num) => x += num
const getX = () => x
```

`x.spec.js`

```
describe('#updateX', () => {
  it('updates x', () => {
    const UPDATE_NUM = 10

    addX(UPDATE_NUM)

    assert.equal(getX(), UPDATE_NUM) // without getX there is no way to get a hold of x
  })
})
```

#### How classes/objects make this easier:

`something.js`

```
class SomeThing {
  constructor() {
    this.x = 0
  }

  addX(num) {
    this.x =+ num
  }
}
```

`something.spec.js`

```
test('updates x', () => {
  const someThing = new SomeThing(),
        UPDATE_NUM = 5

  someThing.addX(UPDATE_NUM)

  assert.equal(someThing.x, UPDATE_NUM)
})
```

## The best solution

use pure functions!

`const addX = (x, num) => x + num`

now you don't rely on external states and testing is as simple as

```
it('adds num to x', () => {
  const UPDATE_NUM = 10

  assert.equal(addX(0, UPDATE_NUM), UPDATE_NUM)
})
```